# Linear regression with $n+m$ parameters

Tags: optimization, linear-regression

I have the following optimisation problem:
$$\min_{\substack{ \theta_1,\ldots,\theta_n \\ \beta_1,\ldots,\beta_m}}\quad \sum_{t=1}^T \frac{1}{2}(\boldsymbol{\theta}_t^\top \boldsymbol{x}_t + \boldsymbol{\beta}_t^\top \boldsymbol{z}_t-r_t)^2 +\frac{1}{2}\sum_i \|\boldsymbol{\theta}_i\|^2+\frac{1}{2}\sum_j \|\boldsymbol{\beta}_j\|^2$$

where $\theta_t\in \{\theta_1,\ldots,\theta_n\}$ and $\beta_t \in \{\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_m\}$.

I would like to solve this problem in the  primal mode, however, the parameters are dependent on each other that plug one in the another does not help. I tried stacking parameters in different ways also, but either it is not possible, or it is very costly in terms of memory. What do you suggest to try?

Comment: What do you mean by 'plug one in the another'. Also you mention that the parameters depend on each other. Do you mean $\theta_i,\beta_j$ are related to each other. That would mean there is some additional constraint

Comment: I meant when we can obtain one from the other one, but it is not the case in this problem. Not in a constraint way, i.e., for computing $\theta_i$ we need to know $\theta_{i+1}$ and vice versa, so there is a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Alternating Minimisation](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.0925v3.pdf) to optimise this objective function. You are optimising two vectors $\theta$ and $\beta$ so you can alternate between solving each variable vector while keeping the other vector constant.

Let $f(\theta_t, \beta_t)$ be your objective function. You can follow these steps to optimise it:

1. Assign $\theta_0$ and $\beta_0$ random values from say a uniform distribution between 0 and 1.
2. Fixing $\beta_{t-1}$, solve for $\theta_{t}$ as $$\theta_{t} = \arg \min_{\theta_t} f(\theta_t, \beta_{t-1})$$You can use gradient descent for this optimisation.
3. Similarly, fixing $\theta_{t}$, solve for $\beta_{t}$ as $$\beta_{t} =\arg \min_{\beta_{t}} f(\theta_t, \beta_{t})$$
4. Repeat steps 2 and 3 until the objective function no longer decreases by some epsilon. As a sanity check, the objective function should never increase between consecutive iterations.

Alternating Minimisation (AM) is a popular method that is used for objective functions where dependencies between variables are tight. Matrix completion is one example where AM is efficient, See Algorithm 1 in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1212.0467v1.pdf) as it gives an idea on solving such objective functions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just wonder if this applies to more than 2 vectors? Here I have $n+m$ vectors to optimise. Could I fix $n+m-1$ and optimise for the last one and then alternate for the rest? Another question is if I could use other approaches than gradient based methods?

Comment: (1) Yes this applies to more than 2 vectors as well - but the convergence guarantees depends on the objective function properties. (2) Using gradient descent is just an example, you can use any optimisation tool that can solve $\arg min_X f(X)$ such as closed-form solution, second-order or cubic order update, etc

Comment: I updated the answer to make it clearer.

Comment: Thanks for clarification and the answer.